# Windows Answer file is not activating the product key

Tags: windows, automation, sysprep, answer-file

I'M trying to enable the product key of our Windows Server with an answer file. The answer file is created with Windows System Image Manager.Is finishing the Answer file without errors but when i check the product key I have to activate this manually.

Hereby the XML which is created by WSIM

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>2</LogonCount>
                <Username>administrator</Username>
                <Domain>test</Domain>
            </AutoLogon>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-NL</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <LogonCount>2</LogonCount>
                <Username>administrator</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Domain>test</Domain>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
            <TimeZone>W. Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <PersistAllDeviceInstalls>true</PersistAllDeviceInstalls>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                    <Key>XXXX-XXXX-XXX</Key>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OfflineUserAccounts>
                <OfflineAdministratorPassword>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </OfflineAdministratorPassword>
            </OfflineUserAccounts>
            <ComputerName>test</ComputerName>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/temp/desktop/adk/install.wim#Windows Server 2016 SERVERSOLUTION" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Use the following command in PowerShell to test the answer file

```
C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /reboot /oobe /unattend:C:\Untitled.xml
```

Comment: Anything in the event log of the system?

Comment: The command that you are using is not powershell but standard commandline (cmd.exe). You should remove the powershell tag from your question.

Comment: What type of key is it?

Comment: @GregAskew we have a mak key

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Nope thing in the event log

Comment: Are you saying the product key is specified, and you only perform the activation manually, or is the product key not specified?

Comment: @GregAskew it's not showing my product key which i put in the answer file.

Comment: @GregAskew did find new erors. After the reboot i lose my static IP.This is the reason why it can not be activated. BUt not sure why it keep losing his static ip

Comment: Actually if the product key is not installed/configured, there would be nothing to activate.

Comment: @GregAskew yes but i am not sure why it does not include the product key since its in the answer file.

Comment: Does it work if you do not set the SystemLocale to nl-nl? Not sure why you would do that if the InputLanguage, UILanguage, and UserLocale are all en-us.

Comment: @GregAskew if I only add product key it restarts and it ask me to accept a terms of condition and ask me to set a password but before we ran the answer file the password etc was already set